# Next+Nextauth Get user's session as a ServerSideProp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session

I'm trying to implement Facebook login and session by using nextauth in a next.js project.
once the user is authenticated I want to retrieve the session and pass it to my component as a server-side prop to avoid unnecessary load time

My **[...nextauth.js]** file

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  providers: [
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
})
```

I've double-checked my env variables FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET NEXTAUTH_URL and SECRET

my **_app.js** file

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

export default function App({
  Component, 
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps }
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

In my **index.js** component, I'm handling the login

```
import { useSession, signIn, signOut,getSession } from "next-auth/react"
import Head from 'next/head'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Login from '../components/Login'

export default function Home({session}) {
  if (!session) return <Login></Login>
  return (
    <div >
      <Head>
        <title>Facebook</title>
      </Head>
      <h1>Signed in as {session.user.email}</h1>
      <Header/>
      <main>
        {/* Sidebar */}
         {/* feed */}
         {/* widgets */}
      </main>
    </div>
  )
  
}
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context)
  return {
    props: { session }
  }
}
```

In mi **Login.js** component I'm just using the signIn method provided by next auth

The thing is:

1. When I try to retrieve the session by using getServerSideProps it doesn't provide me a session and I cannot get to the home page, BUT if I instead use the custom hook inside the component, I get a session and everything works fine, but I think it is better if I pass the session as a serverside prop

```
const session = await getSession() //this works but is client-side
```

- Is there something I'm missing out on? I've read the docs and followed the steps but it doesn't quite work
- besides Is there a difference between **next-auth/react** and **next-auth/client**?
  I have "next-auth": "^4.0.0-beta.7" package installed in this proyect

If anyone could shed some light over this topic and on why I cant get the session as a serverSide prop I would be thankful.

Comment: quick update, doing console.log(session) inside getServerSideProps throws me the session object correctly, the problem is that the index component is not receiving it somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I got it, just changed the way the SessionProvider gets the session on _app.js

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

export default function App({
  Component, 
  pageProps,
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: That should be pointed on the Next Auth docs!